# Xamarin.Forms ios edit calendar event

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a question about the Calendar in iOS
i'm able to create a event into the default calendar with the folllowing code:
ofc after users granted access but not showing the code not important

```
EKEventStore eventStore = new EKEventStore();

var StartDate = GSDFuncties.ToDateString(day, month, year);

//Insert the data into the agenda.
EKEvent newEvent = EKEvent.FromStore(eventStore);
newEvent.StartDate = DateTimeToNSDate(new DateTime(year, month, day));
newEvent.EndDate = DateTimeToNSDate(new DateTime(year, month, day).AddDays(1D));
newEvent.Title = title;
newEvent.Notes = description;
newEvent.Calendar = eventStore.DefaultCalendarForNewEvents;
eventStore.SaveEvent(newEvent, EKSpan.ThisEvent, true, out e);
```

But how can i edit events since its getting duplicated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the correct EventID, you can retrieve it, update it's properties, and then save it again:

```
// load an event by ID
EKEvent event = App.Current.EventStore.EventFromIdentifier (ID);
```

If you don't know the id, you can write a query to find it:

```
NSPredicate query = App.Current.EventStore.PredicateForEvents ( startDate, endDate, null );

// execute the query
EKCalendarItem[] events = App.Current.EventStore.EventsMatching ( query );
```

you will then need to look through the matching events to find the specific one you want and update it.

Xamarin's [EventKit](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_event_kit/) docs contain more examples of working with the calendar.

Comment: Thnx dude indeed already saw it on https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_event_kit/